# Перенаправление с HTTP на HTTPS на сервере Nginx

Tags: nginx, http, https

Поставил сервер на Nginx, сейчас хочу сделать перенаправление. Прописываю в nginx.conf в директиву server следующую строку:

```
return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

Оно вроде и меняет http на https, но пропадает часть адреса и, следовательно, не открывается. То есть, например адрес сервера `192.168.0.10`, при перенаправлении пропадает первая единичнка и получается `https://92.168.0.10`. Что не так?

Comment: в приведённой вами директиве не содержится инструкций по преобразованию имени сервера. значит, выполняются ещё какие-то другие директивы, про которые вы не упоминаете. да и указанная, вполне вероятно, не выполняется — проверьте, изменив её: например, указав `ya.ru` вместо `$server_name`.

Comment: Во-первых, вам скорее всего нужен не $server_name, а $host. Во вторых, экспериментировать с 301 редиректом неудобно, браузер его кеширует и становится непонятно, то ли ошибка в конфиге, то ли кэш. Лучше всегда писать 302 и заменять на 301 только после окончательной отладки

Answer (score 0):

nginx.conf я не трогал.
для перенаправления на https менял конфиг в `.../nginx/sites-enabled/default` (ну или не default если вы уже положили туда свой кастомный конфиг).
должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /YOUR/PATH;
    ssl_certificate /YOUR/PATH;
    ssl_certificate_key /YOUR/PATH;
    ssl_dhparam /YOUR/PATH;

    index index.html; (или что там у вас)

    server_name some.ru www.some.ru;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
server {

    if ($host = www.some.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = some.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name some.ru www.some.ru;
    return 404;
}
```